# What words most commonly follow どういう?

Tags: collocations

Which words most commonly follow どういう?

I know certain collocations already, such as どういうこと and どういう意味.  But my speech isn't always very natural-sounding, and I'm curious if there are any common collocations I don't use at the moment.

Is there a list?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I made the following list this morning using the [*Balanced Corpus of Contemporary Written Japanese (BCCWJ)*](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/) using the freely available 少納言 tool.  Overall, the corpus has 11728 results for どういう, and it shows a maximum of 500 results for any given query.  To overcome this limitation, I searched for どういう and sorted the results by the 後文脈 ("following context") column.  I scanned the list for words that appeared multiple times, and using these results I made a list of collocates to search for.

I ran queries for a number of terms, trying to filter out false positives wherever possible, and then constructed a revised main query by ORing the results I'd found so far inside a negative look-ahead assertion, using these results to repeat the process.  However, very large REs appear to fail, so I was only able to cover about 80% of the results.

Searching for about two hours, I found the following:

```
  ２３５８　どういうこと|事|コト
  １３０３　どういうふう|風　　　　(1140 of which are followed by に)
  １１８４　どういう意味|いみ
  ５４６　　どういうもの
  ５２１　　どういうわけ
  ２３０　　どういう人|ひと
  １９７　　どういう形
  １７２　　どういうところ|所
  １６５　　どういうよう
  １２８　　どういうつもり
  １２３　　どういう関係
  １１３　　どういう時|とき
  １１１　　どういう理由
  ９１　　　どういう状況
  ７６　　　どういう状態
  ６３　　　どういうの
  ５９　　　どういう点
  ５５　　　どういう対応
  ５２　　　どういう影響
  ４４　　　どういう場合
  ３７　　　どういう話
  ３７　　　どういう気持ち
  ３６　　　どういう訳
  ３５　　　どういう内容
  ３５　　　どういう経緯
  ３４　　　どういう問題
  ３４　　　どういう態度
  ３４　　　どういう条件
  ３４　　　どういう仕組み
  ３３　　　どういう行動
  ３３　　　どういう結果
  ３３　　　どういう基準
  ３２　　　どういう反応
  ２９　　　どういう立場
  ２９　　　どういう目的
  ２７　　　どういう方
  ２７　　　どういう仕事
  ２６　　　どういう性格
  ２５　　　どういう神経
  ２５　　　どういう心理
  ２４　　　どういう人物
  ２４　　　どういう根拠
  ２４　　　どういう位置
  ２３　　　どういう役割
  ２３　　　どういう種類
  ２２　　　どういう考え方
  ２１　　　どういう男
  ２０　　　どういう心境
  ２０　　　どういう国
  ２０　　　どういう言葉
  ２０　　　どういう感じ
  ２０　　　どういうお考え
  １９　　　どういう顔
  １９　　　どういうこっ(たちて)
  １８　　　どういう意図
  １７　　　どういう生活
  １７　　　どういう場所
  １６　　　どういうメリット
  １５　　　どういう判断
  １５　　　どういう女
  １４　　　どういう情報
  １４　　　どういう趣旨
  １４　　　どういう指導
  １４　　　どういう考え
  １４　　　どういう会社
  １４　　　どういうタイプ
  １４　　　どういうやり方
  １３　　　どういう手続|手続き
  １３　　　どういう見解
  １２　　　どういう病気
  １２　　　どういう認識
  １２　　　どういう場面
  １２　　　どういう手段
  １２　　　どういう現象
  １２　　　どういう経過
  １１　　　どういう物
  １１　　　どういう生き方
  １１　　　どういう経路
  １１　　　どういう扱い
  １１　　　どういう？
  １０　　　どういう道
  １０　　　どういう順番
  １０　　　どういう構造
  ９　　　　どういう部分
  ９　　　　どういう順序
  ９　　　　どういう手順
  ９　　　　どういう手順
  ９　　　　どういう字
  ９　　　　どういう姿勢
  ９　　　　どういう仕掛け
  ９　　　　どういう結論
  ９　　　　どういう議論
  ９　　　　どういう恰好
  ８　　　　どういう法律
  ８　　　　どういう分野
  ８　　　　どういう処理
  ８　　　　どういう質問
  ８　　　　どういう思いで|思い出
  ８　　　　どういう構成
  ８　　　　どういう気
  ８　　　　どういう環境
  ８　　　　どういう感覚
  ８　　　　どういう印象
  ８　　　　どういうニーズ
  ７　　　　どういう目
  ７　　　　どういう働き
  ７　　　　どういう説明
  ７　　　　どういう設定
  ７　　　　どういう世界
  ７　　　　どういう色
  ７　　　　どういう手続き
  ７　　　　どういう資格
  ７　　　　どういう思い
  ７　　　　どういう姿
  ７　　　　どういう使い方
  ７　　　　どういう御見解
  ７　　　　どういう感想
  ６　　　　どういう料理
  ６　　　　どういう理屈
  ６　　　　どういう日
  ６　　　　どういう地位
  ６　　　　どういう素性
  ６　　　　どういう選択
  ６　　　　どういう者
  ６　　　　どういう社会
  ６　　　　どういう結末
  ６　　　　どういう業種
  ６　　　　どういう活動
  ６　　　　どういうソフト
  ６　　　　どういうイメージ
  ５　　　　どういう目標
  ５　　　　どういう本
  ５　　　　どういう暮らし|暮し
  ５　　　　どういう返事
  ５　　　　どういう体制
  ５　　　　どういう数字
  ５　　　　どういう資料
  ５　　　　どういう子
  ５　　　　どういう原因
  ５　　　　どういう計算
  ５　　　　どういう技術
  ５　　　　どういう機能
  ５　　　　どういう管理
  ５　　　　どういう過程
  ５　　　　どういう運命
  ５　　　　どういう意義
  ５　　　　どういうスタンス
  ４　　　　どういう用件
  ４　　　　どういう発想
  ４　　　　どういう身分
  ４　　　　どういう親
  ４　　　　どういう職業
  ４　　　　どういう工夫
  ４　　　　どういう会話
  ４　　　　どういう歌詞
  ４　　　　どういうゲーム
  ３　　　　どういう理論
  ３　　　　どういう理想
  ３　　　　どういう利益
  ３　　　　どういう用事
  ３　　　　どういう日本語
  ３　　　　どういう日本
  ３　　　　どういう道具
  ３　　　　どういう動物
  ３　　　　どういう動作
  ３　　　　どういう趣味
  ３　　　　どういう手法
  ３　　　　どういう子供|子ども
  ３　　　　どういう攻撃
  ３　　　　どういう言い訳
  ３　　　　どういう言い方
  ３　　　　どういう検査
  ３　　　　どういう経験
  ３　　　　どういう規制
  ３　　　　どういう気持ち
  ３　　　　どういう関わり
  ３　　　　どういう価値
  ３　　　　どういう意識
  ３　　　　どういうニュアンス
  ３　　　　どういうアドバイス
  ３　　　　どういうもん
  ２　　　　どういう歴史
  ２　　　　どういう味覚
  ２　　　　どういう法則
  ２　　　　どういう文書
  ２　　　　どういう日々
  ２　　　　どういう読み方|よみかた
  ２　　　　どういう奴|やつ
  ２　　　　どういう審査
  ２　　　　どういう商売
  ２　　　　どういう修行
  ２　　　　どういう手当て
  ２　　　　どういう作業
  ２　　　　どういう靴
  ２　　　　どういう空間
  ２　　　　どういう歌
  ２　　　　どういう音楽
  ２　　　　どういう運用
  ２　　　　どういうグループ
  ２　　　　どういうせりふ|セリフ|台詞|科白
  ２　　　　どういうお考え方
  ２　　　　どういう。
```

Because of some methodological problems, these results are unlikely to be perfect.  In particular:

1. I was only able to cover about 80% of the results.
2. I wasn't able to confirm that the largest result sets had no false positives, and in some cases I may have made mistakes in the smaller result sets.
3. Smaller result counts are necessarily less accurate due to the smaller amount of data.
4. The way I combined multiple spellings for the same words may also be somewhat inconsistent.
5. In a few cases, どういう may be followed by a larger noun phrase, and the head noun I'm most interested in may appear later where my searches fail to find them.

So please treat these results as approximate only.  Still, the larger numbers should be relatively accurate, and I think I managed to cover the most common collocations, so hopefully this list is helpful anyway :-)

Comment: I didn't know about [this nice interface to BCCWJ](http://nlb.ninjal.ac.jp/headword/R.00016/) when I wrote this answer.